# Why do I get a delay when using CSS3 transitions?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

First up, is it just me?

http://jsfiddle.net/8kc0onqr/

I've made the animations nice and long so they can be distinguished, but on my browser - Chromium Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) - the "closing" animation is delayed by some proportion of the `transition-duration` property.

I've tried various easing functions but they all exhibit the same behaviour, i.e. nothing happens for a while, and then the animation finishes faster than anticipated.

Code from jsfiddle is repeated below, originally shamelessly stolen from atzcss.com

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="checkbox" 
        class="showhide" 
        id="showhide"
    />
    <label for="showhide">
        show/hide
    </label>


    <div class="subpane">
        <pre>
        lots
        of
        stuff
        so
        the
        pane
        is
        nice
        and
        tall
        for
        demonstration
        purposes
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>

.group {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.group label {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: initial;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F4EDFF;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.group input {
    display: none;
}

.group input ~ label:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    /* fa-angle-double-down */
    content: "\f103";
}

.group input:checked ~ label:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    /* fa-angle-double-up */
    content: "\f102";
}


.group input ~ .subpane {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 5s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0;
}

.group input:checked ~ .subpane {
    max-height: 10000px;
    transition: max-height 3s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting case. But stripping it down you find the `max-height` to be the culprit.

When you have the checkbox checked, the pane has `max-height: 10000px`. When you now uncheck the checkbox, the `max-height` is *gradually* animated to `0`. That means, `9999px`, then `9998px`, ...

Until you see the visual effect of the reduced `max-height` it lasts a bit.

Comment: Oh goodness, you're right. To clarify - It's animating several thousand pixels that aren't being used, before it finally gets to the ones that are. But why does it work over at atozcss.com? *edit* It doesn't! I need to find a workaround.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't for me (Firefox). On [this page](http://atozcss.com/beginner/video/the-css-value-of-auto/) collapsing "Summary" shows the exact same behavior.

Comment: @Altreus: Set `max-height` to a more realistic expected value instead of 10000px. That should speed it up. Otherwise you'd more than likely have to use JS.

Comment: @Harry Yes, you're right. The problem is, in situ, it can be anything from 50px to the entire page! I was hoping to avoid JS :(